# live search for a substring in a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, tablerow, livesearch

I have been testing this code which I found on the Internet http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/rFGWZ/ but what I really want to do is to search for a substring in the table row.
For example if I had this table

```
<table>
<tr><th>Unique ID</th><th>Random ID</th></tr>
<tr><td>214215</td><td>442</td></tr>
<tr><td>1252512 ab</td><td>556</td></tr>
<tr><td>2114 </td><td>4666</td></tr>
<tr><td>3245466</td><td>334</td></tr>
<tr><td>24111</td><td>54364</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to search for "ab". Is this possible ? and with which function?

Comment: And do what with it? Return `true/false` if it exists or not? Indicate what col/row/cell it's in? Change it to something else? Also, you should add code you've already attempted to your question.

Comment: Just like in the example I would like to show the whole row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
```

to

```
if (id.indexOf(value) === -1) {
```